# Installing Spark without Maven

Tags: spark-java

I am considering to use Spark in a Java course. My students do not know Maven, so I would like to let them install Spark without Maven.
I downloaded [this jar file](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sparkjava/spark-core/2.6.0/spark-core-2.6.0.jar) and added it to my project, however, I got run-time errors about missing classes (such as slf4j). Is there a simple way to install Spark without Maven?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this very simple POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.stackoverflow.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>hello</artifactId>
  <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <description>Spark Hello</description>
  <inceptionYear>2017</inceptionYear>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

A call to `mvn dependency:tree` yields:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building hello 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ hello ---
[INFO] com.stackoverflow.spark:hello:jar:0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- com.sparkjava:spark-core:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13:compile
[INFO]    +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
[INFO]    |  +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
[INFO]    +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
[INFO]    |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
[INFO]    +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-server:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-common:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-client:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
[INFO]    |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
[INFO]    \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-servlet:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
[INFO]       \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-api:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.229 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-10-14T21:33:25+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/212M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

...Which basically gives you the minimal set of JAR files needed to start the simplest Spark application.

From there, you have several options:

- Download the whole set of JARs and provide it to your students as a `lib/` directory, and have them setup their `CLASSPATH` manually
- Rebuild a single fat JAR with the contents of all required JARs
- Spend some time during the first session to teach the basics of Maven (or Gradle) to your students

[Slightly off-topic]
Admittedly, depending on the time available, I would definitely recommend the third option: Maven (or Gradle) and dependency management are here to stay for a while, and it looks like a must-have skill in this industry. Even if it only means providing your students with a simple POM and introducing them to `mvn clean/package/install` :)

Answer (score 0):

It is way less painful to use a build tool compared to not using  build tool when doing almost any Java development using more than the standard libs. If you want to your students to survive outside of school, and I'm sure you want them to, then include a build tool in your teaching material.

I would personally choose Gradle as it can be used with Gradle wrapper and therefore no installation is needed. Give them a sample project that builds an executable jar and tell them how to build and run the project.